# Does Vermont require inspections of vehicles operated on private land?

Tags: vehicle, vermont

I am considering where I want to move after leaving college, and one of the front runners has been Vermont, until I found that they have annual inspections of motor vehicles. The main reason this matters to me is that I wish to tinker with different sorts of vehicles and engines on my property, and I am concerned that the state government will infringe on my ability to do so. Is my concern warranted?

Comment: There are plenty of hard-core 4x4 rock crawlers (not street legal) in Vermont (and basically just about any state). Note the street-legal, which implies it can be registered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The published statues pertaining to [Vermont vehicle registrations](https://legislature.vermont.gov/statutes/section/23/007/00301) reference operation by a person "on any highway." This specific statute applies to a motor vehicle or trailer.

> A person shall not operate a motor vehicle nor draw a trailer or
> semi-trailer on any highway unless such vehicle is registered as
> provided in this chapter.

There are no references I could find regarding private property within the statutes. It's common to consider that any vehicle operated exclusively on private property can be done so without registration and therefore without the inspection.

Comment: You should check local ordinances. It's probably fine if you're in an unincorporated area, but some municipalities have restrictions on non-working vehicles on your property if they're in view.